# Your projects contains error please fix them before running:Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, maven

I am building android application in which I have imported one of the maven library from this link https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment.My project name is Nfcs and I have no errors in the project and I have added all of the dependencies in my project successfully but when I run the project error window opens saying "Your projects contains error please fix them before running".Please help me find out the error...
[image]

[image]

pom.xml of the library project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>EMV paycard library</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.devnied.emvnfccard</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.devnied</groupId>
            <artifactId>bit-lib4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Unit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
                <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Do you have some items undelined in red in the "Package Explorer" window?

Comment: sorry please check my edit @Rems

Comment: This is strange... If you're working with Maven, you should have a pom.xml file somewhere. This file describes the Maven is going to build your project, or basically generate your .apk . Don't you have that somewhere?

Comment: BTW, as I told you in one of your previous post, Eclipse is not the best choice to work with Maven. But now I have official proof that Maven Build is not supported by the Eclipse Android Plugin... Check this: [Android Studio vs. ADT comparison](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). Check the first table.

Comment: My project is standard android project not maven but the library project I am importing as you can see in the picture is the mavens project.It has the pom.xml.

Comment: please help me out to fix this.Do something @Rems

Comment: OH ok, so forget my previous comment. Could you show me the pom.xml file?

Comment: And the whole error message (because it's cropped in the screenshot)

Comment: see the error picture in edit @Rems

Comment: Have you tried, as the error message suggest, to right click on the _Maven_ project > Maven > Update Project?

Comment: Hahah <3 If it helped you , let me type a proper answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error message says:

```
... Run Maven->Update Project or Use Quick Fix.
```

As you see the error is on your Maven Project, you should follow the hint Eclipse is giving you! And Right Click on your Maven Project > Maven > Update Project.

Usually, Eclipse hints are quite usefull.

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546962/what-does-update-maven-project-do-in-eclipse) to understand what this function is used for. You have to keep in mind that Maven is not the 'native' build manager in Eclipse and therefore needs a little adaptation and additional operations in order for it to work properly.