# Refresh Proguard classes cache

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I am trying to make a build with Proguard, but I get:

```
Warning: my.package.MyClass$innerClass: can't find referenced method...
```

But... This class doesn't exist anymore. I added the class, made a run (maybe also a clean/build by mistake), then removed the class (and made other changes), made a new run, and now I want to clean/build the current code.

But I can't because the build fails with Proguard trying to find a class that doesn't exist...

I tried to delete the entire .m2, with no success. Any idea what step I should do to make Proguard forget about this obsolete class ?

Thank you !

Comment: if it is related to android, you must add right tag ;)

Comment: No it's not. But thanks.

Comment: try maven>update project then clean/build

Comment: Seems good. I am using netbeans. I checked in Options -> Java -> Maven, but couldn't find any "update project" option. I can search for that, but what is it supposed to update compare to "clean" ?

Comment: ok right click on project>check for maven and when you update project click on force update on snapshot

Comment: read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546962/what-does-maven-update-project-do-in-eclipse)

Comment: Ok, I found an option to `reload pom`, which I did, and a Maven option to `update-snapshots` which I activated. But still the same...

Comment: you must add maven tag to get relevent attention

Comment: True, didn't think about it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Oh ! Wait, I think it is working. I don't know exactly why, but I found somewhere that I could run maven clean install -U and it seems to work now.

Comment: this is reason I still use ant ;)

Comment: Oh yeah. I'm so tired of Maven... But it was already so complicated to make everything work the way I needed that I'm not psychologically ready to restart this little game !

Comment: I found the -U on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update. Still not sure if it is this that fixed the issue. You can add it as an answer though. You deserve the points.

Comment: check the link i provided you,it can be useful  :)

Comment: True, but I couldn't find anything similar on NetBeans, and I didn't really wanted to install and parametrize Eclipse just to update my project :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens, the solution is to run:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

It is supposed to force reloading dependencies. I am not entirely sure why it has something to do with the cache of Proguard, but I am now sure that it works.

Find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update)