# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent

Tags: spring, web-services, maven

I am new to webservices and spring, I am trying create a web service using spring maven and i don't what's causing this error on running my **Application.java**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

This is my Application.java

```
package hello;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>restwebservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Try to execute: mvn install

Comment: mvn is already installed

Comment: under maven installation it is showing WORKSPACENOT AVAILABLE 3.0

Comment: I didn't mean that you need to install Maven. I meant that if you're using Maven Then run and execute this Maven command, which is: mvn install

Comment: I tried that but still its not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the spring-context dependency.

Try add this one to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's still showing the same error

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. There seems to be some conflict between `jars` already downloaded in your local maven repository `(${user.home}/.m2/)` and the new `jars` that `Spring Boot` is downloading.

To resolve this:

1. I renamed my old repository to repository.X and recreated a new empty directory named repository.
2. `mvn update` UPDATE - i.e. In Eclipse IDE do: Maven -> Update Project
   [What does Maven Update Project do in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546962/what-does-maven-update-project-do-in-eclipse)
3. `mvn clean install`.

Comment: `mvn update` isn't a valid lifecycle phase.