# Spring Boot Application failed to start with classpath:

Tags: java, spring-boot

I generated a Spring Boot application with Intellij(I am running Windows 10 x64). I clicked enable, but then I got an error like this.:

using 1.8 jdk and intellij ultimate
my teacher running the same project and it working on his computer, probably the problem in my computer.

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

2021-11-24 16:46:21,751 540  [restartedMain] INFO  com.dev.Main - Starting Main on DESKTOP-CMQR5Q7 with PID 15152 (C:\Users\saare\Desktop\rest-server-master\rest-server-master\target\classes started by saare in C:\Users\saare\Desktop\rest-server-master)
2021-11-24 16:46:21,753 542  [restartedMain] INFO  com.dev.Main - The following profiles are active: production
2021-11-24 16:46:21,783 572  [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3934cd95: startup date [Wed Nov 24 16:46:21 IST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-11-24 16:46:21,948 737  [background-preinit] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
2021-11-24 16:46:22,759 1548 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4c3889f2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-11-24 16:46:23,025 1814 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8989 (http)
2021-11-24 16:46:23,034 1823 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service Tomcat
2021-11-24 16:46:23,035 1824 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2021-11-24 16:46:23,109 1898 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-11-24 16:46:23,110 1899 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1327 ms
2021-11-24 16:46:23,337 2126 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2021-11-24 16:46:23,338 2127 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2021-11-24 16:46:23,341 2130 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2021-11-24 16:46:23,341 2130 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2021-11-24 16:46:23,341 2130 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2021-11-24 16:46:23,341 2130 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2021-11-24 16:46:23,386 2175 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory - Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2021-11-24 16:46:23,511 2300 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndexLoader
2021-11-24 16:46:23,512 2301 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory - Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
2021-11-24 16:46:23,725 2514 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat
2021-11-24 16:46:23,732 2521 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndexLoader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.dev.Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndexLoader
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.setResourceLoader(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setResourceLoader(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.index.CandidateComponentsIndexLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
2021-11-24 16:46:23,733 2522 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/saare/Desktop/rest-server-master/rest-server-master/target/classes/]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-can-i-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Did you install al the dependencies with Gradle or maven?

Comment: yes still not working

Comment: Please provide an example of your work

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44740585/8359623

Answer (score -1):

Add the follow dependency between the `<dependencies>` tag in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```