# Is it necessary to always select 'update project' before selecting run as 'maven build...' in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

Do I have to go update project first before run as maven build in Eclipse? (Refer to pics)

[Update Project as seen in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S80FO.png)

[Run as Maven build... option as seen in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04tBb.png)

Can I just select the run as Maven build... option? Will there be any implications if I did that?

Comment: You only need to `update project` if you change something in the Maven configuration, such as adding/removing dependencies. The Project is the Eclipse project, and Eclipse need to be made aware of the build configuration in Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not required to run update project before building with "Run as Maven build ...".
You usually use update project to sync the Eclipse project with the content of the pom.xml. So you use it after changing something in the pom.xml.

See also this question:

[What does Maven Update Project do in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546962/what-does-maven-update-project-do-in-eclipse)